# Listen for array adapter onClick

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, autocompletetextview

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and when you click on an item in my list of AutoComplete words, it is inserting the word I want correctly, however, when I click on the word I want to insert, I want to move my cursor to a different position than the end of the edittext's text. How can I set a listener for my adapter? My code is as follows:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] suggestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_suggestions);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,suggestions);
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.code_text);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setTokenizer(new SColonTokenizer());
```

I can't set it in my text changed listener as this is called every time the user enters a character. How can I listen for an onClick on my array adapter? I know it is possible to do this using a ListView, but my suggestions are handled by the adapter and not making use of a listView to do this.

After clicking, I want to move the cursor inside the parenthesis, I know how to do this using

```
textView.setSelection(textView.getText().length());
```

just I am unsure how to call this after clicking on an array adapter item
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OnItemClickListener` like

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)           
     {
      textView.setSelection(textView.getText().length());
     }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! I did not realise that I needed to set the listener to the textView, I thought that it was for the adapter that I need to set the listener.